# Using Vagrant with SaltStack, how do I start nginx after providing custom configuration

Tags: nginx, vagrant, salt-stack

I have a Vagrant boxset up to provision with salt. When I do a fresh `vagrant up` (after a `vagrant destroy`), nginx defaults to port 80 and the default welcome page, despite not being configured to. I can fix it by manually running `sudo nginx -s reload` inside the guest, but I would prefer not to use a manual workaround.

Here's my `salt/roots/salt/nginx/init.sls` file:

```
nginx:
  pkg:
    - installed

nginx run:
  service.running:
    - name: nginx
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca
  require:
    - file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca
    - file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - pkg: nginx

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://nginx/nginx.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644

/etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://nginx/dotmanca.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
  require:
    - pkg: nginx

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca:
  file.symlink:
    - target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
  require:
    - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
  file.absent:
    - name: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
  require:
    - pkg: nginx
```

The nxginx server is installed and runs properly after provisioning, and the configuration files show up in the correct location.

I need to either reload the config in nginx after my custom files get placed, or somehow hold off running the nginx service until the files are in place.

Comment: Few things to troubleshoot. (1) Run your SLS on minion using `salt-call salt.sls YOUR_SLS`. (2) Add comment inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (to introduce config change). (3) Re-run your SLS. [?] Do you see Salt reacts to the changes and restarts the service? (4) Post Salt execution output if not. (5) Avoid using spaces in state ids like `nginx run` (not sure, but it's just smells bad - ids with spaces are hardly universal in any formal language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to know more about the `require` bits. I had them where states should go, and not under the states themselves.

My file should have looked like this:

```
nginx:
  pkg:
    - installed

nginx_run:
  service.running:
    - name: nginx
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca
    - require:
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca
      - file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - pkg: nginx

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://nginx/nginx.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644

/etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://nginx/dotmanca.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dotmanca:
  file.symlink:
    - target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - require:
      - file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/dotmanca

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
  file.absent:
    - name: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx
```

Comment: For me the changes were not obvious without diff checking, thus there is a clarification:
for all `require` blocks were added an indent and dash.

Answer (score 2):

You can always run restart command automatically - see [`cmd.run`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run). Just make it depend on service state.

However, it would be my last resort. Salt is able to use dependencies (or [requisites](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) in Salt's terms) and make sure proper config file content is used before start of the service (or restart service if config file changes detected).